# Calling this function inside of this one and am getting an error of getString not defined

Tags: python-3.x

This is my code, please help me analyze

```
class stringManipulator(object):

    def getString(self, strInput=input("Enter String: ")):
        return strInput

    def printString(self):
        strOutput = getString()
        strOutput = strOutput.lower()
        print(strOutput)
```

Comment: You should be calling getString as `self.getString()`. Why do you need a class for this anyway?

Comment: Just to note that having `strInput=input('Enter String: ')` as a default argument is iffy at best (as soon as the code is imported - it's going to sit and wait for input)... If you really want to do that, I'd suggest re-writing it as `def get_string(self, prompt='Enter String: '): return input(prompt)` so the input is only executed as necessary but allowing a prompt that can be overridden if needs be.

Answer (score 1):

You need to refer to the class method with `self.`, like below

```
strOuput = self.getString()
```

That's how Python will know where to look for the function (scope).